# Use type from index in child types

Tags: typescript

I have a bunch of data that's built into an object literal.  The keys of this object also exist in each of the child objects in this object and I'd like to enforce that with typescript:

```
type People = {[NAME in string]: { name: NAME; age: number }};

const people: People = {
    Jeff: { name: "Jeff", age: 30 },
    Fred: { name: "Freddy", age: 25 }, // no error, name evaluates to string
    Sally: { name: "Sally", age: 35 },
};
```

In the past I've done similar things using string unions:

```
type People = {[NAME in "Jeff" | "Fred" | "Sally"]: { name: NAME; age: number }};

const people: People = {
    Jeff: { name: "Jeff", age: 30 },
    Fred: { name: "Freddy", age: 25 }, // ERROR: Type '"Freddy"' is not assignable to type '"Fred"'.  ts(2322)
    Sally: { name: "Sally", age: 35 },
};
```

But for my current use case maintaining a separate union type in addition to the object would be excessive.

**Is it possible to use the key type from an indexed object in the children of that object?**

Comment: What is your current use case? I don't know if this is feasible, but I would not be too surprised if not–it feels like bad design to duplicate like this.

Comment: @gqstav I'm trying to add typing to an existing schema format defined in JSON.  It defines all of its types in one flat object with a matching key and `typename` prop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I can do is like this:

```js
type People<T> = { [K in keyof T]: { name: K; age: number } };

function createPeople<T extends People<T>>(people: T): People<T> {
    return people;
}

const people = createPeople({
    Jeff: { name: 'Jeff', age: 30 },
    Fred: { name: 'Freddy', age: 25 }, // ERROR: Type '"Freddy"' is not assignable to type '"Fred"'.  ts(2322)
    Sally: { name: 'Sally', age: 35 },
});
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work with my use case, but I genuinely think this is as close as I'm going to get - thanks!